# How to Create New User (without Form) in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create new User in laravel 5.2.

I try the following to create user,

```
   public function createUser()
    {
     return User::create([
        'name' => 'Name',
        'email' => 'user@mail.domain',
        'password' => bcrypt('password')
    ]);
   }
```

It creates the record of the User.

but, i can't use this account to login.

If i tried, i get error as "**Credential not matched !**".

But i know the credential, because i create it.

Also **i don't want FORM** to submit and create user.

I need direct level of user creation at Backend.

I hope, it's possible. But don't know the way to achieve.

Any Solution for this ?

[I use laravel's **AUTH Library**]

"I need to Inject the AUTH library to create new user, and follow the default wave of AUTH libary. I just want user creation for Auth Library and ensure it as same as Auth creates"

Answer (score 2):

you've to save the password in laravel using

```
Hash::make("the password")
```

and to check the password you can use

```
Hash::check($input_password, $database_password)
```

and don't forget to import the Hash library or use facade.

If you don't want to create form to submit new user, you can use seeder from laravel for dummy data or you can use postman to hit the specific endpoint that you already created.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Try this :

```
Hash::make($password);
```

and check passworg

```
Hash::check($password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution for my issue.

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = 'user_name
    $user->email = 'user@mail.com';
    $user->password = bcrypt('*******');
    $user->remember_token = Str::random(60);
    $user->save();
```

Thanks to All..